# .dot net core redirect is not excecuting

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

first of all i like to stress im new to asp. Im trying to implement Oauth which requires me to redirect to a generated url. So far everything works except to rerouting. On click, it just refreshes the page and in the console im able to see the url. Why is it not redirecting?

```
public async void OnGetTestMethod() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("test method called");
    await Index();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Console.WriteLine("index called");
    var a = this.HttpContext.Session.GetString("login");  
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("login", "oof"); 
    Console.WriteLine("index called");

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    // if (accessToken != null)
    // {
    //     // This allows the client to make requests to the GitHub API on the user's behalf
    //     // without ever having the user's OAuth credentials.
    //     client.Credentials = new Credentials(accessToken);
    // }

    try
    {
        // The following requests retrieves all of the user's repositories and
        // requires that the user be logged in to work.
        var repositories = await client.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
        // var model = new IndexViewModel(repositories);
        
        // return View(model);
        return null;
    }
    catch (AuthorizationException)
    {
        // Either the accessToken is null or it's invalid. This redirects
        // to the GitHub OAuth login page. That page will redirect back to the
        // Authorize action.
        Console.WriteLine("trying to redirect");
        return Redirect(GetOauthLoginUrl());
    }
}
```

frontend

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="TestMethod" class="btn btn-primary">test button</button>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/

Thats where you should start. .net core brings a standard implementation for oauth

Comment: According to the docs, only a certain amount of external authentication providers are implemented. I'm trying to let this work with the Github API. Any idea if this doc is applicable?

Comment: Oauth is a protocol, so other external providers work just fine.
Maybe this one can help: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/12/secure-your-aspnet-core-app-with-oauth
You just need to replace the configuration parts that it fits to the github API